# Using a JSON Dictionary with Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, dictionary

I have two json dicionary files, each with the same terms from two different languages.

```
{
   "Account" : {
      "AccountLockText" : "Your account is locked",
      "Login" : {
         "CreateAccount" : "Create an account",
         "LoginBtn" : "Login",
         "LoginHeader" : "Login"
      }
   }
}
```

And I have a dictionaries.d.ts:

```
declare module "dictionaries" {
    var Account: any;
}
```

To be called and used with typescript in my application. Sad part is that said file is empty, and I have no idea how to make that kind of connection.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: so is it empty in what way?

Comment: The dictionaries.d.ts is empty apart the Account var. Theres no connection to the JSONs files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a simple interface to describe a JSON message I'm getting back from a service call:

```
interface AccountData {
    Account: {
        AccountLockText: string;
        Login: {
            CreateAccount: string;
            LoginBtn: string;
            LoginHeader: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of it in action (I'm just parsing a JSON string to show you how it adds the type information from the interface I use in the type annotation).

```
const data = `{
"Account" : {
    "AccountLockText" : "Your account is locked",
    "Login" : {
        "CreateAccount" : "Create an account",
        "LoginBtn" : "Login",
        "LoginHeader" : "Login"
    }
}
}`;

let result: AccountData = JSON.parse(data);

alert(result.Account.Login.CreateAccount);
```